# Obtaining a replacement UK driving licence

Tags: driving-license

I currently live overseas and have done so since 2010.  I previously held a UK driving license, but have somehow managed to mislay it.  Can you advise how I can get a replacement.  Thank you.

Comment: Where do you live?  If you live in the EU, you are supposed to replace it with a local license; but that may be hard if you've lost the original.  In the worst case you may have to retake the test locally.

Comment: That is also true elsewhere. A comment in a recent question quoted Maryland, USA as 60 days.

Answer (score 1):

UK drivers licenses can be replaced, even from overseas, but only if the applicant resides in Great Britain. See [this UK govt. page](https://www.gov.uk/apply-online-to-replace-a-driving-licence), which addresses license replacement, and contains the following text:

*...To replace your licence you’ll need to: be a resident of Great Britain (there’s a different service in Northern Ireland), not be disqualified from driving for any reason pay £20 by MasterCard, Visa, Electron or Delta debit or credit card provide addresses where you’ve lived for the last 3 years.*

Thus, to replace your previous license, you'll have to lie to DVLA about your residence. None of us would recommend that course of action.